# Ubuntu 20.04 updater ran this morning - too big for my screen issue has returned after reboot

Tags: 20.04

I had this issue before and it has returned December 6, 2020. In settings-display-resolution I only show 640 x 480 with no other choices, used to show 1080 x 960 I believe. I have a System76 Gazpro6. I have tried backdating mutter and put it in hold but no joy.

Comment: I tried the Lorenz Keel fix but it did not work. When I run "chmod +x ~/.local/bin/fix-font-size.sh", does it create a folder or where would I go to look at the script - not sure if it ran on reboot. It is visible in Startup Preferences.

Comment: Could this be an nvidia problem or is it just a bug. I am running a propietary 340.108 driver.

Comment: I tried so many things that I just went ahead and reloaded 20.04 and ran updates. All good, I am not that good at fixing probs, even after ten plus years using ubuntu, but I do now how to start over!